# Converting 32-bit float to IEEE 80-bit

Tags: c++, assembly, floating-point, double

I'm trying to convert a 32-bit float into an extended precision 80-bit float.
I'm using MSVC x86. I tried the following inline ASM code:

```
void Convert32To80(float *value, void *outValue)
{
    __asm
    {
        fld float ptr [value];
        fstp tbyte ptr [outValue];
    }
}
```

Here, `void *outValue` is a buffer that is large enough to hold 10 bytes.
This looks right to me, but it's crashing when it's run.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "crashing when run." What specific error(s) do you get?

Comment: I get no specific error. It's a C++/CLI dll which is loaded from managed code (it's something with the ASM, other inline ASM stubs work fine). I get this:

"The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x64f9fca1, on thread 0x1904. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack."

Comment: You need to check with your debugger which instruction causes the crash. Perhaps your outValue is bad (NULL or something like that)?

Comment: I tried that actually, but for some reason I can't step into the function. Not even in disassembly view.

Comment: @Jakob I bet you get no error because of the bone-headed decision of MS to run the FPU with the exception masks cleared! You're always much better off doing FP work with Borland tools.

Comment: @David Is that just an optimization option?  Not sure about current processors, but the older ones execute faster with the exception masks cleared.  If optimization is disabled, does MS set the exception masks?

Comment: @Brian I don't really know why they do it. I can't imagine it makes any real difference to performance. I've actually no idea how MSVC deals with things like FP divide by 0, overflow etc. Is it just the presence of NaNs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this should do it:

```
void Convert32To80(float *value, void *outValue)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax,dword ptr [value] 
        fld dword ptr [eax] 
        mov ecx,dword ptr [outValue] 
        fstp tbyte ptr [ecx] 
    }
}
```

All I did was wrote some C code to do the same, but for a float to double conversion, looked at the dissasembly and then modified as necessary.

Note that I am no expert with MSVC and I'm not 100% sure that I can use the EAX and ECX registers like that without saving/restoring them. Others may know more and offer corrections.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. Didn't think 'value' inside the inline ASM would be the pointer to it on the stack!
Thanks a lot again.
About the EAX and ECX registers, the Intel ABI says they can be used without saving them, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Use caution...  Not everyone completely follows the Intel ABI.  Best to check with the compiler vendor as they're the only one that knows for certain.

Comment: @Brian, @Jakob I was thinking the same thing, but wasn't sure how to express myself. I looked at a similar routine but coded with pure C and just assigning a float to a double. The prologue and epilogue were essentially identical.  But I agree, I'd want to check the register saving conventions, but I'm really know little of MSVC being more of a Borland guy.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** Note for posterity: Apparently, MSVC 2010 has no type for 80bit floating point types, so the obvious solution in C or C++ code along the lines of

```
float inValue = 666.666f;
long double outValue = (long double)inValue;
```

does NOT work, and you are actually forced to directly use assembly language.

Comment: Would indeed, except in MSVC 2010 long double is a synonym for double, which is 64-bit.